# is there process substitution in Bourne Shell like that in Bash?

Tags: shell, unix, process, substitution

I'm trying to use cmp to compare outputs of two commands (Bourne shell):

cmp <(ls $file1) <(ls $file2)

It works well in Bash but cannot work in Bourne. Is there any solution? Thanks so much!

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: I too was hoping for this. I have shell scripts that would be easier to understand if I had process substitution available, buy with most of my scripts being Bourne shell compatible I would have to remember that some scripts need to be executed with bash

Answer (score 2):

Process substitution is (or used to be) implemented using named pipes. You could use `mkfifo` directly to recreate the same behavior:

```
mkfifo pipe1 pipe2
ls $file1 > pipe1 &
ls $file2 > pipe2 &
cmp pipe1 pipe2
rm pipe1 pipe2
```

But besides performances, you won't gain much compared to going thought regular files...